# C++: How to random a sequence of diferrent numbers?

Tags: c++, function

I want to random a sequence of numbers:
For Example: A sequence of 1 to 9
3 7 6 5 1 9 4 2 8
You see, this is not a duplicating number. I think it involves to: `srand(time(NULL))`

Thanks.

Comment: your are looking for `std::shuffle`.

Comment: No, usually it involves `std::shuffle()`, `srand()` (or other generators) does not guarantee in any way, that duplicating number won't be there

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Take a minute to read through [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides the mentioned [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) function, check out the [pseudo-random generating facilities in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: The answer to your question is literally the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

Answer (score 3):

The simplest, most elegant way (in *my* opinion) is to use [std::iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) and [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Here's an example (based on the links above):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(9);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), 
        std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
// 'v' is now a vector containing a random
// ordering of the integers 1-9.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to include stdlib.h

```
/* ... */
srand(time(NULL));
int v = rand() % 10; //random [0, 10)
/* ... */
```

After this you should put value on an array (or vector) and check every time the values, example:

```
#include <algorithm> //for find
/* ... */
std::vector<int> v;
while(v.size() != 10) {
    int x = rand() % 10;
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
    if(it == v.end())
        v.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: That's overly complicated and slow. Just fill a vector with the needed numbers (`std::iota` makes that easy), then `std::shuffle` it. Just a few lines of code, fast and elegant and no messing with horribly bad functions like `rand`. Btw, you are creating bias with that modulo (`%`) and `time()` is a *terrible* seed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, in honesty, `time()` is an OK seed for many usages. Granted, not for cryptography, but completely suitable in other cases.

Comment: @SergeyA even outside crypto you'll still get unpleasant results when two instances of the program run within the same second. Which can easily happen - for example if this was in a webservice, getting queried thousands of times per second.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, imagine a single-device game (big user of RND), for example (as I am not necessarily sure why webservice would need a RND). For such use case, time as RND seed is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

You should include ctime and stdlib.h

```
    srand((int) time(0));
    int p;
    for(int j=1; j<= 9; j++)
        {
            p = ((rand() % 99) %9 )+1;
                      cout <<p <<endl;

        }
```

This code should generate random numbers from 1 to 9.